# Why elasticsearch can search with space?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
const searchParams = {
        index: "products",
        body: {
          from: offset,
          size: limit,
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: {
                term: {
                  name: `*${fullTextSearch}*`,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };
```

I have a searchParams like this but when name= "gold ring". It didn't show any data. But if name input without space name = "gold", it work.

Why elasticsearch can search with space

Comment: @Val No I think it's string because when I console.log(hits[0]) it like this: 

`{
    _index: 'products',
    _id: 'cNRaG4wBp0BTRqv9SIyQ',
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        id: 22,
        name: 'gold ring',
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `name` is of type `text`, hence it is analyzed into tokens.
Searching with a `term` query won't analyze the input text and will search for an exact value `gold ring` which probably no `name` field contains.

If, however, you change your query to use `match` instead of `term` you should see results. And you should also remove the leading and closing wildcards:

```
const searchParams = {
    index: "products",
    body: {
      from: offset,
      size: limit,
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: {
            match: {                       <---- change this
              name: `${fullTextSearch}`,   <---- change this
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```